# Which is the best way to Volley parsing another class in Android?

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-asynctask, android-volley

After parsing the json structure from the web with the help of the volley library, I save it to the Room database. I decided to perform this operation in another class other than MainActivity. But I don't know how to get feedback from there. what is the best way

From here on, I will pull the data from the Room database and display it in Recyclerview, but how do I know if the process is finished?

MainActivity

```
       MainDatabaseParsing mainDatabaseParsing=new MainDatabaseParsing(context);
       mainDatabaseParsing.sliderDataRequest();


From here on, I will pull the data from the Room database and display it in Recyclerview, but how do I know if the process is finished?
```

Parsing Class

```
public class MainDatabaseParsing {
Context context;


   public MainDatabaseParsing(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }

 public void sliderDataRequest() {
       sliderItems.clear();
       JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
               Constant.SLIDER_JSON, null,
               response -> {
                   long baslangic = System.currentTimeMillis();
                   try {
                       JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Array");
                       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                           if (!object.getString("related").equals("advertised")) {
                               SliderModel sliderItemData = new SliderModel();
                               sliderItemData.setId(object.getInt("id"));
                               sliderItemData.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                               sliderItemData.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
                               sliderItemData.setDesc(object.getString("desc"));
                               sliderItemData.setTag(object.getString("tag"));
                               sliderItemData.setRelated(object.getString("related"));
                               sliderItemData.setContent(object.getString("content"));
                               sliderItemData.setUrl(object.getString("url"));

                               sliderItems.add(sliderItemData);
                           }
                       }


                       new InsertSliderData().execute(sliderItems);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
       });
       stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
       stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
       queue .add(stringRequest);
   }


// Room DB Saving
  class InsertSliderData extends AsyncTask<List<SliderModel>, Void, Integer> {
       @SafeVarargs
       protected final Integer doInBackground(List<SliderModel>... arg0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < arg0[0].size(); i++) {
               sliderDao.insertSlider(arg0[0].get(i));
           }

           return sliderDao.getAllData().size();
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
           Log.d("TAG_JSON_FOOD_DB1", "result: " + result);
           setSliderSize(result);
           super.onPostExecute(result);
       }
   }


}
```

Comment: research about callback functions

Comment: As said by @a_local_nobody you can use callbacks or observables for this task.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Taranmeet Singh Can you give an example link? I can confirm if you post it as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: i've used this post to explain to people how to work with async requests, there is more than sufficient info in here to show you how to get it done, otherwise you'll find plenty of information available online as well for how to make use of callbacks